# How to use wildcard in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my Firebase database structure:

```
ft-records
  userX@gmail_com
    2013-01-01 00:00:00 GMT
        addedByUser: "userX@gmail.com"
        notes: "Boooo"
        time: "2013-01-01 00:00:00 GMT"
    2013-01-02 10:00:00 GMT
        addedByUser: "userX@gmail.com"
        notes: "Yeaah"
        time: "2013-01-02 10:00:00 GMT"
  userY@gmail_com
    2013-01-01 03:00:00 GMT
        addedByUser: "userY@gmail.com"
        notes: "Ok"
        time: "2013-01-01 03:00:00 GMT"
```

I can query this data like this for the authenticated user e.g. userX@gmail_com

```
let userRecords = self.ref.child(self.user.email.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "_", options: .literal, range: nil))

userRecords.queryOrdered(byChild: "time").queryStarting(atValue: startOfDayDateString).queryEnding(atValue:endOfDayDateString).observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in ... } )
```

But if I wanted to query all notes from all users for a specific date, how do I achieve this?

I needed somehow a wildcard to read all children from root and then query by time of each child. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Could I do something like this?

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "ft-records/*")
```

Answer (score -2):

You'd use Firebase Database queries for that.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "ft-records")
let query =ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "time").queryStarting(atValue: "2013-01-02 00:00:00 GMT").queryEnding(atValue: "2013-01-02 23:59:59 GMT")
```

For more information see the [Firebase documentation on filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data) and the [Firebase codelab for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/#codelabs).

Comment: I don't understand. The children of `ft-records` are `userX@gmail_com` and  `userY@gmail_com`. There is no `time` to query. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah right, there's an extra level in there. You can't query across multiple dynamic levels.

Comment: Downvote reason: I think the answer should be updated with the one that you provided as a comment, if that is still the case. (Plus, by your own admission, it misinterprets the OP's question.)